# Python 3 & Selenium - How to combine multiple For Loops - scraping Web Table

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, html-table, selenium-chromedriver

I'm completely new to Python (and Stack Overflow), I'm trying to find an efficient way to extract data from a table on an internal website, which has multiple pages.

The following code works fine, but as the website has 16 pages, I need to find a way please, to simply this For Loop.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
\\\

first = '//*[@id="container"]/table/tbody/tr['
second ="]/td["
last = "]"

for n in range(1,rows+1):
    for m in range(1,cols+1):
        final_path = (first+str(n)+second+str(m) + last)
        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text
        print(table, end= " ")
    print()

#  - Click on Page 2 and get all the table data from there.

driver.find_element_by_link_text("2").click()

for n in range(1,rows+1):
    for m in range(1,cols+1):
        final_path = (first+str(n)+second+str(m) + last)
        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text
        print(table, end= " ")
    print()

#  - Click on Page 3 and get all the table data from there.

driver.find_element_by_link_text("3").click()

for n in range(1,rows+1):
    for m in range(1,cols+1):
        final_path = (first+str(n)+second+str(m) + last)
        table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text
        print(table, end= " ")
    print()

\\\
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another enclosing for loop.

```
for page_no in range(2, 17): # 2...16
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_no)).click()

    for n in range(1,rows+1):
        for m in range(1,cols+1):
            final_path = (first+str(n)+second+str(m) + last)
            table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(final_path).text
            print(table, end= " ")
        print()
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, that does go through all 16 pages very quickly,  but none of the table data is captured, with the exception of the last page. Is there a way to add a delay so the page data is captured before the next page is clicked? Appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies Justin! I copied and pasted only the additional for loop that you wrote and didn't indent the other two for loops, so the code ran your for loop independantly to the others, hence why it wasn't working, this is perfect now, thank you so much!! :)